$[n,k,3]$ linear code exists iff Hamming bound holds
Show that: $[n,k,3]$ linear code exists iff the Hamming bound holds, i.e.
$$ q^k\leqslant \frac{q^n}{1+n(q-1)}$$
I have no idea how to show this, does the construction of such code have anything to do with the Hamming code? Why $d=3$ so special?
Any hints, references are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Let $H$ be a $(n-k)\times n$ whose columns are $n$ non-zero distinct vectors in $\mathbb{F}_q^{n-k}$ with the first non-zero entry being $1$. (The above inequality shows that we can always find $n\leqslant \frac{q^{n-k}-1}{q-1}$  such vectors) We can carefully select these vectors such that there exists $3$ vectors linearly dependent, since $n\geqslant 3$.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a linear code with $H$ being its parity-check matrix. Clearly it is a $[n,k]$ code. As for $d$, notice that every 2 columns of $H$ are linearly independent, $d\geqslant 3$. By construction, $d=3$.
